# Python code to redirect stdin and stdout to a shell script

Tags: python, shell, command-line, stdout, stdin

I am trying to write a program that reads from a file and writes to a new file using the command line. I am using the CommandLine class and using ArgParse to accept different args as well as the file names for input and output. I am trying to redirect stdin and stdout to these files. However, I keep getting an error that I put at the bottom of the code below. Am I inputting the arguments to the command line incorrectly, or is something else going on? All of my files are in the same folder.

```
class CommandLine() :
'''
Handle the command line, usage and help requests.

CommandLine uses argparse, now standard in 2.7 and beyond. 
it implements a standard command line argument parser with various argument options,
a standard usage and help, and an error termination mechanism do-usage_and_die.

attributes:
all arguments received from the commandline using .add_argument will be
avalable within the .args attribute of object instantiated from CommandLine.
For example, if myCommandLine is an object of the class, and requiredbool was
set as an option using add_argument, then myCommandLine.args.requiredbool will
name that option.

'''

def __init__(self, inOpts=None):
    '''
    CommandLine constructor.
    Implements a parser to interpret the command line argv string using argparse.
    '''

    import argparse
    self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Program prolog - a brief description of what this thing does', 
                                         epilog = 'Program epilog - some other stuff you feel compelled to say', 
                                         add_help = True, #default is True 
                                         prefix_chars = '-', 
                                         usage = '%(prog)s [options] -option1[default] <input >output'
                                         )
    self.parser.add_argument('inFile', action = 'store', help='input file name')
    self.parser.add_argument('outFile', action = 'store', help='output file name')
    self.parser.add_argument('-lG', '--longestGene', action = 'store', nargs='?', const=True, default=False, help='longest Gene in an ORF')
    self.parser.add_argument('-mG', '--minGene', type=int, choices= (0, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000), action = 'store', help='minimum Gene length')
    self.parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', action = 'append', nargs='?', help='start Codons') #allows multiple list options
    self.parser.add_argument('-st', '--stop', action = 'append', nargs='?', help='stop Codons') #allows multiple list options
    self.parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 0.1')  
    if inOpts is None :
        self.args = self.parser.parse_args()
    else :
        self.args = self.parser.parse_args(inOpts)

C:\Users\Zach\Documents\UCSC\BME 160\Lab 5>python findORFsCmdLine.py --    minGene=3
00 --longestGene --start=ATG --stop=TAG --stop=TGA --stop=TAA <tass2.fa     >result.
txt
usage: findORFsCmdLine.py [options] -option1[default] <input >output
findORFsCmdLine.py: error: the following arguments are required: inFile,     outFile
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that you did not provide `inFile` and `outFile`. This seems confusing because you did indeed provide `<tass2.fa` and `>result.txt` on the command line.

On the command line `<` and `>` have special meaning. `<tass2.fa` is handled by `bash` (or whichever shell you use) and it opens the file `tass2.fa` and sends the contents to your program over `stdin`. It then removes that from the list of command line arguments because `bash` has already taken care of it.

A similar thing happens with `>result.txt` where any output from your file that normally goes to `stdout` such as print calls will be written to that file. Again `bash` handles this so your program never gets the argument from the command line.

To make sure the filenames go to your program you need to remove the `<` and `>` symbols.

---

In addition to that, the way you are call `add_argument` for `inFile` and `outFile` is not correct. Using `action='store'` simply stores the value of the argument under the given name. This is the default action so doing that is redundant.

You need to tell `add_argument` that these are file types. Then you can use these as files and read and write as you desire.

```
parser.add_argument('inFile', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('outFile', type=argparse.FileType('w'))
```

If you wish to allow these arguments to be optional and use `stdin` and `stdout` automatically if they do not supply a filename then you can do this:

```
parser.add_argument('inFile', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
    nargs='?', default=sys.stdin)
parser.add_argument('outFile', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
    nargs='?', default=sys.stdout)
```

---

You say you are writing a program that reads from a file and writes to a new file using the command line and go on to say that you are trying to redirect these files to stdin and stdout.

If it is really your intention to redirect the input and output files using the shell with the `>` and `<` operators, then you do not need to call `add_argument` with `outFile` at all. Just let the shell handle it. Remove that line from your program and use `print` or similar to send your content to `stdout` and that file will be created. You will still need the call `add_argument('inFile', ...`.

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion by telling add_argument that the inFile is a file type. I'm getting the same error as before. One thing to note is that my program makes use of a class that reads the fastA input file. That object is initialized with the file name passed to it as a parameter from which it reads.


`myReader = sequenceAnalysis.FastAreader(myCommandLine.args.inFile)`

Comment: @Zach Did you remove the `<` from the file name on the command line?

Comment: I just tried running it without the `<` and I get this error:
`C:\>python findORFsCmdLine.py tass2.fa >r
esulted.txt --longestGene --minGene=300 --start=ATG --stop=TAG --stop=TGA --stop
=TAA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "findORFsCmdLine.py", line 217, in <module>
    main()
  File "findORFsCmdLine.py", line 202, in main
    for head, seq in myReader.readFasta():
  File "C:\Users\Zach\Documents\UCSC\BME 160\Lab 5\sequenceAnalysis.py", line 24
5, in readFasta
    with open(self.fname) as fileH:
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='tass2.fa' mode='r' encoding='c
p1252'>`

Comment: I asked my professor about this and he has told me that the simple use of `<` and `>` should suffice to run the program on the command line. If possible I'd like to use his implementation. He showed an example in class and on his Mac it runs fine with the code I initially posted. Could this be some issue with my OS since I am running Windows?

Comment: @Zach It appears that the TypeError is happening because when you have `add_argument` set up with `type=argparse.FileType('r')` then `myCommandLine.args.inFile` is actually a file object and passing that to `FastAreader()` would generate an error because it expected a file name and not a file object. If you just need the file name then the way you posted it is fine but you can`t use `<` and `>` or `inFile` and `outFile` would be blank and you get the error you originally posted.

Comment: The only way that I can get it to work using `<` and `>` is with the `FileType` and the default value of `sys.stdin` in `sys.stdout` in my second example. I do not know how it could work with the redirect operators with the code you originally posted. Without seeing the rest of your code that calls CommandLine it is hard to know what is really going on.

Comment: I just tried it using this code:
`self.parser.add_argument('inFile', action = 'store', help='input file name')`
and this on the cmdline:
`C:\Users\Zach>python findORFsCmdLine.py tass2.fa >res
ult.txt --longestGene --minGene=300 --start=ATG --stop=TGA --stop=TAG --stop=TAA`
and it worked.
I think I'm seeing where my confusion came from before. I think if I change the value that I am passing to the constructor for the FastAreader to stdin, then I can use the `<` and `>` notation.

Comment: Exactly, if you read from stdin then `<` will work. If you use my code with the default of stdin, then you can pass a file name without the `<` or using `<` and both will work.

Comment: Nevermind, I just tried my own suggestion above and it didn't work. I really want to be able to use the `<` and `>` operators as it is how my professor wants us to do it. Would it be possible for me to send you my code privately?

Comment: I just read your response Noah and I tried it, but I get an error when using the `<` notation.
`C:\>python findORFsCmdLine.py <tass2.fa >re
sult.txt -lG -mG=300 -s=ATG -st=TAG -st=TGA -st=TAA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "findORFsCmdLine.py", line 217, in <module>
    main()
  File "findORFsCmdLine.py", line 202, in main
    for head, seq in myReader.readFasta():
  File "C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\UCSC\BME 160\Lab 5\sequenceAnalysis.py", line 261,
 in readFasta
    with open(self.fname) as fileH:
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='cp
1252'>`

Comment: Feel free to send a private message via twitter.